# EPPlus - pivot tables not adding date columns

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm having to generate a pivot table report for work that breaks down resource allocation on on a weekly basis. (i.e. Resource 1 is working 10 hours on 9/10/2018, 15 hours on 9/17/2018, etc...) I got this working using the Excel Interop API, however, it's choking in EPPlus. Any values where the column is not headed by a date can be added without issue, but when a date is involved it just straight won't add the column. There's no errors thrown and no documentation that I can find that explains what's going on. It acts as if it's been successfully added, but when the worksheet is opened there's nothing there, if you click on the column in the PivotTable Fields menu then it adds without issue.

[View that I see after adding a few non-date columns and attempting to add the date columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIsWo.png)

Test code that I'm running to add these columns:

```
ExcelWorksheet forecast = Workbook.Worksheets[ForecastSheet.SheetName];
ExcelPivotTable pivotTable =
Worksheet.PivotTables.Add(Worksheet.Cells[1, 1], forecast.Cells[forecast.Dimension.Address],
    "PIVOT_" + SheetName);
pivotTable.RowFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields[AbstractRawDataSheet.ResourceNameColumn - 1]);
pivotTable.RowFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields[AbstractRawDataSheet.ProjectNameColumn - 1]);
pivotTable.DataOnRows = false;
pivotTable.ShowHeaders = true;
pivotTable.ColumnGrandTotals = true;
pivotTable.GrandTotalCaption = "Grand Total";

for(int i = AbstractRawDataSheet.SysTotalHoursSum - 1; i < AbstractRawDataSheet.SysFilteredHours + 2; i++)
    pivotTable.DataFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields[pivotTable.Fields[i].Name]);
```

note: The +2 should add 01/01/2017 and 01/08/2017, a log message reports that 01/01/2017 12:00:00 AM and 01/08/2017 12:00:00 AM are fetched in this loop, however, they are not added.